# Unable to register/check userId after authorization from Auth0

Tags: java, angular, auth0

I have an login flow setup that should register the userId created in the database when a user registers for the first time, otherwise return the existing userId if the user already exists.

The auth0 application has allowed callback url: http://localhost:4200/callback.

/callback injects a service and uses that service to call a registerUser method.

registerUser then makes an http get call to the backend and attempts to capture the response.

```
  registerUser() {
    this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8080/api/user/register", {responseType:"text"})
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.userId= data;
      })
  }
```

The backend code checks if user already exists in DB, returns string userId;

```
    //Grabs the token value from authentication in order to extract User info and save to DB
    @GetMapping("/register")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String register(Authentication authentication){
        Jwt jwt = (Jwt) authentication.getPrincipal();

        try{
            return userRegistrationService.registerUser(jwt.getTokenValue());
        }catch (Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

---------------------------------------------------------------------
UserRegistrationService

public String registerUser(String tokenValue){
        //Call User info endpoint

        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .uri(URI.create(userinfoEndpoint))
                .setHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", tokenValue))
                .build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .build();


        //Fetch Details and save to DB
        try {
            // Get Http response body
            HttpResponse<String> responseString = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            String body = responseString.body();

            // Map response onto User fields, set deserialization on unknown false as we do not need all fields

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            UserInfoDTO userInfoDTO = objectMapper.readValue(body, UserInfoDTO.class);
            //Check if the user is already in DB
            Optional<User> userBySub = userRepository.findBySub(userInfoDTO.getSub());
            if(userBySub.isPresent()){
                return userBySub.get().getId();
            } else {
                // Map body onto User object
                User user = new User();
                user.setFirstName(userInfoDTO.getGivenName());
                user.setLastName(userInfoDTO.getFamilyName());
                user.setFullName(userInfoDTO.getName());
                user.setEmailAddress(userInfoDTO.getEmail());
                user.setSub(userInfoDTO.getSub());

                // Save to DB
                return userRepository.save(user).getId();
            }
        }catch(Exception exception){
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred while registering user", exception);
        }
    }
```

When I sign in, I get a 401 error from register endpoint and then get get redirected to /home despite there being no navigation/router elements in the html or .ts files for /callback (or app-routing.module.ts). If I manually navigate back to /callback then the register endpoint returns a userId correctly and I can see it added to the DB. I am also not navigated away from the /callback page.